# Sort these elements in descending order?

Tags: c++, pointers, qsort

Experimenting with qsort and it runs perfectly for me. I use function pointers throughout the program and some other features I am not used to (i.e. such as void pointers).

I want the elements arranged in descending order (i.e. as opposed to ascending order), however.  What can I do to achieve this?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  // Required for qsort
#include <cstring>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int compare_strs( const void *arg1, const void *arg2 );
int compare_ints( const void* arg1, const void* arg2 );

int main()
{
    char * shrooms[10] = 
    {
        "Matsutake", "Lobster", "Oyster", "King Boletus",
        "Shaggy Mane", "Morel", "Chanterelle", "Calf Brain",
        "Pig's Ear", "Chicken of the Woods"
    };

    int nums[10] = {99, 43, 23, 100, 66, 12, 0, 125, 76, 2};

    // The address of the array, number of elements
    // the size of each element, the function pointer to 
    // compare two of the elements
    qsort( (void *)shrooms, 10, sizeof( char * ), compare_strs ); 
    qsort( (void *)nums, 10, sizeof( int * ), compare_ints ); 

    // Output sorted lists
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        cout << shrooms[i] << endl;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
        cout << nums[i] << endl;

    return 0;
}

int compare_ints( const void * arg1, const void * arg2 )
{
    int return_value = 0;

    if ( *(int *)arg1 < *(int *)arg2 )
        return_value = -1;
    else if ( *(int *)arg1 > *(int *)arg2 )
        return_value = 1;

    return return_value;
}

int compare_strs( const void * arg1, const void * arg2 )
{
    return ( _stricmp( *(char **) arg1, *(char **) arg2 ) );
}
```

The program outputs in ascending order (i.e. starting with Calf Brain), but I am trying to get it to start with Shaggy Mane (i.e. descending order).  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Swap the logic in your comparator functions? (and note: your current `int` comparator can simply subtract right from left. the result will be negative if left < right, 0 if they're equal, and positive if left > right.)

Comment: Why are you using `qsort` in C++?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you very much or the response.  I feel stupid for missing that before I posted my code.  

I am looking to sort the strings in descending order as well, however. Since it just calls the string compare function, how would I do this?

Comment: Also, `qsort( (void *)nums, 10, sizeof( int * ), compare_ints ); ` is not correct. It is by sheer luck that `int` and `int *` are the same size on your system. You should always use the size of the *element* in your sequence. To generally ensure this, use `sizeof(nums[0])`. So your invoke would read: `qsort( (void *)nums, 10, sizeof( nums[0] ), compare_ints );`

Comment: @JerryCoffin I am using all sorts of "sorts" at the moment.  qsort was just the one I was having some difficulty to work until I finally got the code above working (i.e. with the exception of getting the strings to appear in descending order).

Comment: @WhozCraig Again, thank you very much for the insight. So the proper syntax is always sizeof(<name>[subscript])?

Comment: @MrPickle5 If you're set on using qsort, and you already have comparators in the ascending direction, you can generally wrap them by "opposite" comparators as user93353's answer demonstrates, then use those in similar invokes to qsort(). I also concur with Ajay, in using `std::sort` and either a custom comparator with your current arrays or `std::string` and a random access container like `std::vector` or `std::deque`., but it sounds like you're familiar with these and are just interested in learning more about how `qsort` works.

Comment: @MrPickle5 pretty much, yeah. And none of the `sizeof` matters once you embrace `std::sort` instead; it is iterator-based (and imho much more intuitive).

Comment: Solved the problem and you guys are going to slap me.  All I did was replace arg1, with arg2 and it worked somehow??

I will try and use std::vector, std::string, std::sort and other more elegant solutions to sorting.  Just trying to find my niche with C++.  :)

Comment: @MrPickle5: Well, of course it worked. You changed the order of parameters, and thus inverted the logical result of your comparison. `A < B ==> !(B < A)` (as long as it is a well-defined strict total order).

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) in conjunction with [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater):

```
std::string shrooms[10] = 
{
    "Matsutake", "Lobster", "Oyster", "King Boletus",
    "Shaggy Mane", "Morel", "Chanterelle", "Calf Brain",
    "Pig's Ear", "Chicken of the Woods"
};

std::sort(shrooms, shrooms+10, std::greater<std::string>);
```

If you don't want to use `std::sort` simply inverse either the result of your comparison function or reverse your result.

Comment: +1, and I'm assuming not using `std::begin` and `std::end` on the chance this isn't a C++11 environment. I really like those wrappers too.

Answer (score 2):

Better use [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/). There is no need to play around complicated `qsort`.
Also, you should use `std::string` for storing strings, and `std::vector` to store them!

EDIT:
*Someone posted a commenet that std::sort won't magically reverse the sorting logic, so here is my reply:*

And why not? `std::sort` algorithm takes a comparator also! Return negative-Boolean value, and you are done!

Comment: Yes. But if he isn't able to do it in qsort - why do you think he will be able to it in std::sort.

Comment: qsort is so-C, not needed in modern C/C++ programs. May be Quicksort algorithm is good, but it uses lot of stack memory, and call-back is hard to maintain. Void-pointer are bug prone! Standard C++ now has umpteen sorting techniques. Why live in stone age?

Comment: qsort is very much needed in modern C Programs. You do know that C and C++ are different languages and that std::sort isn't available in C. I am fully in favour of using std::sort in C++. However, that isn't my point. The OP is missing the fact that descending order sort is just the reverse of ascending order sort & hence he needs to reverse his comparator. If he is missing this in C, he will also miss it in std::sort. Zeta's answer suggests std::sort but also addresses this point - and it's an actual answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @Ajay: A properly written qsort should *not* use a lot of stack space. When properly written, it limits stack depth to ~log(N), so (for example) sorting a million elements uses about 20 stack frames in the worst case, and 4 billion elements uses about 32 stack frames.

Comment: World is moving to parallel programming using templates and STL, and you want to be buried in void-pointer call backs? Other languages has nifty features, and people use and appreciate them. C++ too has them, but rarely used by C++ professionals, and is then classified as 2nd grade "old school" language!

Comment: @user93353, cout is very much C++ !
And sorry, I am not worried about "Answer", this is just my opinion! :)

Comment: Yes. cout is very much C++. My reply was to the following sentence in your comment - `qsort is so-C, not needed in modern C/C++ programs`. qsort is very much needed in modern C Programs.

Comment: Okay my bad. I always call "C/C++" as single term, to refer C++, having many C-features!

Comment: BTW, the whole Linux Kernel is written in the old school language.

Comment: Is that a point to debate? I refer new software products. I am aware, still many new apps/drives/services etc are on top of C. I didn't say C is bad, it has more development cost. Managed languages are less in development, but C/C++ is close to the metal.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the logic of your comparator functions.

```
inline int rcompare_strs( const void *arg1, const void *arg2 )
{
    return -1*compare_strs(arg1, arg2);
}

inline int rcompare_ints( const void* arg1, const void* arg2 )
{
    return -1*compare_ints(arg1, arg2);
}

qsort( (void *)shrooms, 10, sizeof( shrooms[0] ), rcompare_strs ); 
qsort( (void *)nums, 10, sizeof( nums[0] ), rcompare_ints );
```

Comment: You know, even `C` has a unary minus operator :)

Comment: @rici - yeah I know. But I always write negation this way other than for simple literals or variables - it's more readable for me. I find the unary minus operator very easy to overlook when in front of a function call while reading.

Comment: W*h*a*t c*a*n I s*a*y*? R+e+a+d+a+b+i+l+i+t+y i+s+ s-u-r-e-l-y p!e!r!s!o!n!a!l b---u---t::: I personally prefer not having excess punctuation. YMMV.

Comment: @rici :-) There is a difference between redundant and incorrect punctuation.